# Sketchware Unable to connect to Firebase Realtime Database after the DB URL change

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, sketchware

Recently Firebase Realtime database has gone through internal change in its Database URL.
Previously it was **MYDB.firebaseio.com.**
Since last 5-6 days, it has changed to **MYDB-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com**.

After this change, **Sketchware** is unable to connect to the newly created databases.
Any suggestion or work around?

Comment: try changing your project id in the firebase config file to your project id + the new added part "-default-rtdb", I tried editing it in the admin sdk json file used by my php project and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @YosraHamza, manually adding the additional URL part to our db name solved the problem.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

project id: "example-id"

put the project id from "example-id"
to "example-id-default-rtdb"

and the bucket URL should be
"example-id.appspot.com"